# Replicate eclipse screen for java code

Tags: listings, java, eclipse

Hi there is a method to replicate the eclipse screen with keyword colors for a java code like this
[image]
I tried this but it doesn't work

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}           
\geometry{top=3.0cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[italian]{babel}     
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Box}% Listing -> Algorithm -> change name to listing enviroment
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}% List of Listings -> List of Algorithms


\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{pred}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{pgrey}{rgb}{0.46,0.45,0.48}
\definecolor{apricot}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}


\lstset{language=Java,
    %uncomment the following line for tiny numbers beside the box
    %numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray}, stepnumber=2, numbersep=10pt, 
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    commentstyle=\small \color{pgreen},
    keywordstyle=\small \color{pblue},
    stringstyle=\small \color{pred},
    basicstyle=\small \ttfamily,
    tabsize=2,
    moredelim=[il][\textcolor{pgrey}]{},
    moredelim=[is][\textcolor{pgrey}]{\%\%}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
    TimeDiscretization timeDiscr2 =
        new TimeDiscretizationFromArray(new double[] {0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0,
        1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0});
        
        BrownianMotionFromMersenneRandomNumbers brownianMotion2 = new BrownianMotionFromMersenneRandomNumbers(timeDiscr2, 2, numberOfPaths, 3231);
        MonteCarloMultiAssetBlackScholesModel bsmodelV2 = new MonteCarloMultiAssetBlackScholesModel
                (brownianMotion2,initialValues, riskFreeRate, volatilities, correlations);
        
        EuropeanOption call = new EuropeanOption(maturity,strike);
        RandomVariable valueOfCall = call.getValue(2.0, bsmodelV2);
        double priceCall = AnalyticFormulas.blackScholesOptionValue(initialValues[0], riskFreeRate, volatilities[0], maturity, strike);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please specify what "it doesn't work" means. It's doesn't compile? It doesn't give the expected result? What don't you like with the result? As it is, your code isn't compilable so it can't be tested.

Comment: @Miyase Sorry :), It doesn't give the expected result. I posted a compilable version